# Deploying Visual Studio SQL Server 2014 application

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-migration

I'm new on SQL Server. I recently completed a program in Visual Studio C++ using SQL Server 2014 as DB. The DB contains many tables and some of that are very large (more the 100K rows). Now I have to install my program into a Windows 7 computer where SQL Server 2012 express is installed with SSMS. Which is the best way to copy my DB tables into the other computer?

Comment: Recommend editing to remove the C++ tag. This has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: We use Sql Server Data Tools (SSDT) but there are many other ways. You could write a SQL script and use sqlcmd

Comment: Set your database compatibility level to SQL 2012 and take a backup. then restore the database on your new server. I'm not sure this will work, but it worth to try

Comment: Backup and restore works, but keep in mind 1. connection string in express edition is different to standard/enterprise edition, so you may need to check. And 2 express edition has DB size limitation